# \Cref not working

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

```
\documentclass[Afour,sageh,times]{sagej}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:Introduction}

\Cref{sec:discussion}

\section{Discussion}
\label{sec:discussion}

\end{document}
```

The above minimal example doesn't work as when I use \Cref, it doesn't work and
prints only ??. Can anybody please help me out with this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Have you tried compiling a second and third time?

Comment: And you remembered to compile at least twice?

Comment: Compiled like 10 times but still din't work.

Comment: Does it work with `\documentclass{article}`? I do not have `sagej`, can you give a link?

Comment: @samcarter- https://uk.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/sage_latex_template_0.zip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sagej` document class sets `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}`. This means that absolutely no sectioning headers are numbered anywhere in the document. Therefore, both `\section{Introduction}` and `\section{Discussion}` produce unnumbered sectioning headers.

LaTeX's cross-referencing mechanism works by associating each `\label` instruction with the most recently incremented counter variable. Since your MWE contains no counters that are incrementef, `\Cref` cannot possibly generate a valid cross-reference. That's why you get `??`.

[image]

If you want numbered section-level headers, set `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` somewhere in your preamble. Do be aware, though, that this change quite likely defeats the design choices of the `sagej` document class and, as such, may not be viewed favorably by editors.

Comment: Incidentally, the issue is not confined to the macros of the `cleveref` package. Do verify for yourself that `\ref` doesn't work either in your MWE.